# how to create multiple reactive in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R shiny and having a struggle with it.

I have data set called 'performance' similar to below.

```
Date         A       B
2020-08-01  50      100 
2020-08-03  50.95   34.9695
2020-08-03  54      1.39927
2020-09-01  150     350
2020-09-05  96.03   129.96
2020-09-07  68.41   35.9961 
2020-10-01  75      200
2020-10-05  72.41   67.125  
2020-11-01  35   250
```

I want to make reactive for date and A column
If user select 2020-08-01~2020-08-03 in 'dateRangeInput' and type in 50 in 'numericinput' section then I want output of table should look like as below.

```
Date         A       B
2020-08-01  50      100 
2020-08-03  50.95   34.9695
```

Here is the code I got so far.
I am not sure whether how to make two different reactive in R shiny

```
library(shiny)
   

ui <- fluidPage(

  title = "Performance Table",

 dateRangeInput("daterange", "choose date",
                start = min(performance$Date),
                end = max(performance$Date),
                min = min(performance$Date),
                max = max(performance$Date),
                format = "yyyy/mm/dd",
                seperator="-"),

  numericInput("num", "A", value = 0, min=0, max=500),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(

        'input.dataset === "performance"',

        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in performance:",

                           names(performance), selected = names(performance))

      ),
       

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(

        id = 'dataset',

        tabPanel("performance", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
     

      )

    )

  )

)

 

server <- function(input, output) {
          

 filteredData <- reactive({
      req(input$daterange)
      df <- performance[performance$Date >= input$daterange[1] &
                        performance$Date <= input$daterange[2] &
                        performance$A == trunc(input$num), ]

     df[sample(nrow(df), 1000, replace = T), ]

    })


  output$data <- renderTable({
      performance[, c("performance", input$show_vars), drop=FALSE]
  }, rownames=TRUE)
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(filteredData()[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])

  })
                 

}   
 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

when I run above code and select date 2020-08-01~2020-08-03 and type 50 in numericinput then I get output as below which is different to what I expect for the output. Is there a way that I can see the decimal values as well?

```
Date         A       B
2020-08-01  50      100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised the previous version I had created for you (which was working) to include a `numericInput`.

In `server`, if you want to filter based on column `A`, you can add:

```
performance$A == input$num
```

Note that the filtering will be done before you `sample`.

If you want to match numbers and ignore decimal places, you can truncate with `trunc`:

```
trunc(performance$A) == trunc(input$num)
```

This would ignore decimal places of the `A` column in the data, as well as the number entered in `numericInput`.

Also, in your first version you only have one value from `input$num`. This differs from `dateRangeInput`, where you have a vector of length two as a result, and use `input$daterange[1]` and `input$daterange[2]` when utilizing the result.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Performance",
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                 start = "2020-08-01",
                 end   = "2020-11-01"),
  numericInput("num", "A", value = 0, min = 0, max = 500),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(performance), selected = names(performance)
                           )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
      )
    )
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange)
    df <- performance[performance$Date >= input$daterange[1] & 
                      performance$Date <= input$daterange[2] & 
                      trunc(performance$A) == trunc(input$num), ]
    df[sample(nrow(df), 1000, replace = T), ]
  })
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filteredData()[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben but somehow for the numericinput it doesn't return what I expected. if I type 50 in the numeric input then it return random number in table (like 100, 60 etc)

Comment: A is decimal, would this be matter?

Comment: I thought you wanted to filter numbers great than 50 in your example...please clarify what you want to do with the number. What do you expect happen if 50 entered? Please describe more.

Comment: Did you *only* want to include rows where A equals 50, if someone enters "50"?

Comment: No, I want to filter the number that user input in the numeric input section. If user select 2020-08-01 and 50 then only first line of data(relevant data that user has inputted) shows in the table and if user select 2020-10-01 and 75 then the only relevant data the user has select shows in the table. That's I am aiming to do

Comment: If you want values that are *exactly* 50 (or whatever is in `num` input) for "A", then try `performance$A == input$num` instead of `performance$A >= input$num`

Comment: I have change performance$A >= input$num, to performance$A == input$num, and seems it works but if the value is in decimal like 50.15 then this won't come up in the table

Comment: You can round the `input$num` if you want to get the closest integer (50.15 becomes 50), or you can truncate and remove the decimal (50.99 becomes 50).

Comment: Is there a way to get all the relevant numbers, like if user type 50 then all the number start from 50 select and show it in table because I need those decimal as well.

Comment: If you want to include 50, 50.2, 50.9, 50.333333, etc. (or any number that starts with 50 and includes any decimal) you might try truncating using `trunc()` such as `performance$A == trunc(input$num)` ... that way, if someone enters 50.7 it will be treated as 50 (the decimal places are all dropped)

Comment: When I run the code with trunc() and type 52.7 in numeric input then it only returns column with 52 even though there are columns with 52.7. It's not the way I wanted, I want out put should come out 52, 52.5,52.7etc. if user enter 52 in the numeric input section...

Comment: If that’s not it, please take time to edit your question. Include more data with decimals. Describe more what output should look like with more examples. You need to describe more of what you need...much more detail and examples. It’s not clear to me.

Comment: I have edited the question, would this help better to understand?

Comment: Why does 54.95 show up if 50 is entered? I don’t understand. And if 54.95 is ok to include then why not just 54? All of this is confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry I made you confusing, I made mistake when I entered the data set. If user enter 50 then I want output to show all the values that start with 50 like 50, 50.95 etc and if user enter 54 then the output should be 54, 54.3etc.. but when I used trun() then it only returns 50 so I want to know if there are ways to get output of all the relevant values including decimal point number even if user type 50 in the numeric input section. sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see my comment earlier: you can try `trunc(performance$A) == trunc(input$num)` which works for me...or you can do `trunc(performance$A) == input$num` if the user is not going to be entering decimal numbers. Did you try that? See edited answer for details.